# What are proper EEG frequency bands and electrode placements for imagined speech?

Tags: eeg, signal-detection, speech, signal-processing

I am doing an EEG experiment about imagined speech recognition. Which frequencies will have the most relevant information? I chose the frequency band [4-40] Hz as a start, mainly because of signal processing considerations. Filtering out the remaining frequencies basically removes the DC voltage and most of the EOC artifacts. 
 Which frequencies should I select?

Also which channels will contain the signal (*i.e.*, the most relevant data)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A study by D’Zmura et al. ([2009](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://cnslab.ss.uci.edu/speechattention/content/DZmuraHCIInternational2009.pdf&ei=nfoTVbS-CpCC8gXOy4LgCA&usg=AFQjCNEMv02n223j2Gy0U740F1WclKrY1A&sig2=vJimVjXvZn1XY-zXdCf2yA&bvm=bv.89217033,d.dGc)) in which two syllables were spoken in imagination showed that imagined speech information was present in EEG alpha, beta and theta bands. The **beta band** (13-18 Hz) proved most informative. The most informative electrodes were located mainly near the top of the head (**vertex**) where electromyographic artifacts had least influence.

They used various signal processing steps (standard low-pass filtering to remove 60 Hz line artifact, DC filtering, signal enveloping etc.) to clean up their signal. Please refer to the reference list for specific signal processing details.

<sub>**References**</sub>

- [D’Zmura et al. Lecture notes in computer science 2009;40-8. HCI International](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://cnslab.ss.uci.edu/speechattention/content/DZmuraHCIInternational2009.pdf&ei=nfoTVbS-CpCC8gXOy4LgCA&usg=AFQjCNEMv02n223j2Gy0U740F1WclKrY1A&sig2=vJimVjXvZn1XY-zXdCf2yA&bvm=bv.89217033,d.dGc)
- [Brigham & Kumar, iCBBE 2010](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5515807)